# Update Next.js environment variables at run time

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I'm working on a project using Next.js and I need to set environment variables at runtime (not build time). My goal is to have my CI/CD run the `next build` command to create a production build, and then use `next start` to run the application while passing in an environment variable file name, such as `env.dev`, `.env.qa`, `.env.stg`, or `.env.production`.

I've looked through the Next.js documentation on environment variables, but I haven't found any guidance on how to do this. I've also tried setting `NODE_ENV=test next start`, but the application still only uses the environment variables from the .env.local file.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to update environment variables at runtime in a Next.js project?

Thanks in advance.